# IEnumerable and IEnumerator in the same class, bad idea?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, ienumerator

Is this a bad idea?

```
Private Class GH_DataStructureEnumerator(Of Q As Types.IGH_Goo)
  Implements IEnumerable(Of Q)
  Implements IEnumerator(Of Q)
  ....
  ....
  'Current, MoveNext, Reset etc.'
  ....
  ....

  Public Function GetEnumerator_Generic() As IEnumerator(Of Q) _
                  Implements IEnumerable(Of Q).GetEnumerator
    Return Me
  End Function
End Class
```

This class is only visible as an IEnumerable(Of T) readonly property, and it saves me an additional class that wraps IEnumerator(Of T). But somehow it just seems wrong. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bad idea because the solution will break down if someone attempts to enumerate your collection more than once at the same time.

For example:  This will break in some way

```
For Each cur1 in yourObj 
  For Each cur2 in yourObj
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", cur1,cur2)
  Next
Next
```

Comment: Or even not at the same time, quite possibly :)

Answer (score 7):

Definitely a bad idea. In particular, it means that two calls to `GetEnumerator` will return references to the same object - when they should return *independent* iterators.

Now having said that, the C# compiler will generate classes which implement both types if you use iterator blocks... but it goes to great lengths to make sure that it gets it right. I suggest you don't put yourself through that pain :)

Comment: Jon, my life's goal is to avoid pain, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

From [Implementing IEnumerable](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2003/04/10/49957.aspx):

> Do provide a GetEnumerator() method that returns a ***nested public struct*** called “Enumerator”.

*By the way, this website is maintained by Brad Abrams - one of the authors of [Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613).*

Comment: I've never liked this particular suggestion - it encourages mutable structs, which can behave in evil ways.

Comment: @Jon - That is a good point but I think that in this case it's not the worst idea.  It's definitely a trade-off between performance (less memory pressure with a struct) and having a mutable struct which could introduce wierdness in the application.  I think given the fact that most developers do not work with the enumerator instance directly that having it be a mutable struct is a good trade-off for the performance benefit. But in general I agree that mutable structs should be avoided.

Comment: Brad makes the trade-off very clear: Implementing this pattern involves having an extra public type (the Enumerator) and several extra public methods that are really there just for infrastructure reasons.  These types add to the perceived complexity of the API and must be documented, tested, versioned, etc.  **As such this pattern should only be followed where performance is paramount.** Consequently, this should *not* be used most of the time where performance is not too critical.

Comment: @Mehrdad - Fair enough but I would argue that a type that implements `IEnumerator` doesn't really create _that_ much API complexity.  Good point though :)

Comment: I would suggest that IEnumerable should return a class rather than a struct, though for performance reasons it may be helpful to have a GetEnumerator method not associated with IEnumerable which returns a struct.  If a GetEnumerator method exists and returns a struct, both VB.net and C# will duck-type it to avoid boxing; invoking GetEnumerator through IEnumerable, however, will require the enumerator to be cast to a boxed IEnumerator, eliminating any performance benefit a struct would have.