# Json DeSerialization of an array to IEnumerable failing

Tags: c#, json, json.net

cs which has the following property:

```
 public CustomerExtensions CustomerExtensions { get; set; }
```

The CustomerExtensions class:

```
[DefaultMember("Item")]
public class CustomerExtensions  : 
     IEnumerable<CustomerExtension>, IEnumerable, IEnumerator
{
       public CustomerExtensions();
       public CustomerExtensions(List<CustomerExtension> customerExtensions);
}
```

The CustomerExtension class:

```
public class CustomerExtension 
{
    public CustomerExtension();
    
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }       
    public int CustomerType { get; set; }       
}
```

So when I desrialing the json stream like this:

```
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(response, custDefualtSettings());
```

Response:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "$type": "Common.Customer, PublicKeyToken=f291d5e4",
    "CashPrice": 47042.74,
    "AmountFinanced": 47042.74, 
    "CustomerExtensions": {
        "$id": "4",
        "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Common.CustomerExtension, PublicKeyToken=f291d5e4]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f291d5e4",
        "$values": [
            {
                "$id": "5",
                "$type": "Common.CustomerExtension, PublicKeyToken=f291d5e4",
                "CustomerId": 11946,
                "CustomerType": 1,                             
            },
            {
                "$id": "5",
                "$type": "Common.CustomerExtension, PublicKeyToken=f291d5e4",
                "CustomerId": 11046,
                "CustomerType": 3,                             
            }        
        ]
    }
```

The deserializing is failing with following error :

> Cannot create and populate list type Common.CustomerExtensions. Path 'CustomerExtensions.$values', line 1, position 2725.

Can someone please point in right direction..?

Answer:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class CustomerExtensionsConverter : JsonConverter<CustomerExtensions>
{
    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override CustomerExtensions ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, CustomerExtensions existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var list = serializer.Deserialize<List<CustomerExtension>>(reader);
        return new CustomerExtensions(list);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, CustomerExtensions value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: There isn't enough information here.  Can you post the json object you are trying to deserialize?

Comment: Hi dogyear my response object is the json object

Comment: 1) Is `CustomerExtensions` intended to represent a read-only collection of `CustomerExtension` objects?  2) Implementing both `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator` on the same class is not recommended, it implies that it is impossible to enumerate the class multiple times at once, e.g. in a nested loop.  See [IEnumerable and IEnumerator in the same class, bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2519168/3744182).  Why are you doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CustomerExtensions` implements `IEnumerable<CustomerExtension>`, so the deserializer by default will be expecting it to serialize and deserialize from a json array. It will try to create a new instance, then call `Add(CustomerExtension item)` to populate it. However, you don't implement `IList`, so there is no `Add()` method that it can use, and it doesn't know what to do.

Why do you need a custom class for this? There is no additional logic in your class, wouldn't it be enough to have `public List<CustomerExtension> CustomerExtensions { get; set; }`?

**Edit**

Since you aren't able to change the class definition, you can create a custom JsonConverter instead:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class CustomerExtensionsConverter : JsonConverter<CustomerExtensions>
{
    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override CustomerExtensions ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, CustomerExtensions existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var list = serializer.Deserialize<List<CustomerExtension>>(reader);
        return new CustomerExtensions(list);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, CustomerExtensions value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use the converter, add it to the JsonSerializerSettings object when calling `Deserialize`:

```
var settings = custDefualtSettings();
settings.Converters.Add(new CustomerExtensionsConverter());
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(response, settings);
```

I haven't tested this, but it should give you a general idea of what the implementation would look like.

Comment: Thank you Andrew but  these classes are not created by us. They do have additional logic just did not put them for readability. Is there a way I can handle this in Json stream response?

Comment: Create and register a custom `JsonConverter<CustomerExtensions>` that deserializes the next element as a `List<CustomerExtension>`, then uses your constructor to create a new instance

Comment: Thank you Andrew..but pretty new to the Json serialization/deserialization concept. Any starting pointer please?

Comment: @Ravio see the updated answer. We've switched to `System.Text.Json` at my company, which is similar but not completely the same so you may need to double-check the code I posted, but it will give you a starting point

Comment: Thanks a ton  Andrew. Updated my question with your Answer . Only the return type of your readJson had to be changed. everyting was perfect